# Trouble writing Tic Tac Toe game in C#

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

I'm not sure where I went wrong with the logic here but I'm having trouble getting this game to run correctly. As far as I can tell the logic of the Check4Winner function is sound and I've even gone as far as to give separate counter variables per win condition. The CheckInput function just checks if the input given is valid and whether or not the position chosen is already marked by an "X" or an "O". I believe the problem is the way the main function is set up but I'm not sure what else to try. I'm using a while loop in the given code but I've also tried an if statement but was having trouble moving to the next player. I am new to C# as you can probably tell. Any help or explanation of where I've gone wrong would be greatly appreciated!

[EXAMPLE: things like this keep happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLzLU.png)

```
public static string[,] board = new string[,]
        {
            {"1","2","3"},
            {"4","5","6"},
            {"7","8","9"}
        };

    public static int player = 0;
    public static string choiceX;
    public static string choiceO;


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (!Check4Winner(board))
        {
            Board();
            CheckInput();
        }

        Console.Clear();

        if (player % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{board[0, 0]} | {board[0, 1]} | {board[0, 2]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"__|___|__");
            Console.WriteLine($"{board[1, 0]} | {board[1, 1]} | {board[1, 2]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"__|___|__");
            Console.WriteLine($"{board[2, 0]} | {board[2, 1]} | {board[2, 2]}");
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2 wins!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{board[0, 0]} | {board[0, 1]} | {board[0, 2]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"__|___|__");
            Console.WriteLine($"{board[1, 0]} | {board[1, 1]} | {board[1, 2]}");
            Console.WriteLine($"__|___|__");
            Console.WriteLine($"{board[2, 0]} | {board[2, 1]} | {board[2, 2]}");
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1 wins!");
        }

        Console.Read();





    }


    public static void Board()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine($"{board[0, 0]} | {board[0, 1]} | {board[0, 2]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"__|___|__");
        Console.WriteLine($"{board[1, 0]} | {board[1, 1]} | {board[1, 2]}");
        Console.WriteLine($"__|___|__");
        Console.WriteLine($"{board[2, 0]} | {board[2, 1]} | {board[2, 2]}");

        if (player % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 1's turn: Please choose a position to place an 'X':");
            choiceX = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player 2's turn: Please choose a position to place an 'O':");
            choiceO = Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    public static void CheckInput()
    {
        if (player % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(choiceX, out int choiceXint))
            {
                if (choiceXint <= 9 && choiceXint >= 0)
                {

                    switch (choiceXint)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (board[0, 0] != "X" && board[0, 0] != "O")
                            {
                                board[0, 0] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[0, 0]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }

                        case 2:
                            if (board[0, 1] != "X" && board[0, 1] != "O")
                            {
                                board[0, 1] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[0, 1]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }

                        case 3:
                            if (board[0, 2] != "X" && board[0, 2] != "O")
                            {
                                board[0, 2] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[0, 2]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 4:
                            if (board[1, 0] != "X" && board[1, 0] != "O")
                            {
                                board[1, 0] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[1, 0]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 5:
                            if (board[1, 1] != "X" && board[1, 1] != "O")
                            {
                                board[1, 1] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[1, 1]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 6:
                            if (board[1, 2] != "X" && board[1, 2] != "O")
                            {
                                board[1, 2] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[1, 2]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 7:
                            if (board[2, 0] != "X" && board[2, 0] != "O")
                            {
                                board[2, 0] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[2, 0]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 8:
                            if (board[2, 1] != "X" && board[2, 1] != "O")
                            {
                                board[2, 1] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[2, 1]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 9:
                            if (board[2, 2] != "X" && board[2, 2] != "O")
                            {
                                board[2, 2] = "X";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[2, 2]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (int.TryParse(choiceO, out int choiceOint))
            {
                if (choiceOint <= 9 && choiceOint >= 0)
                {
                    switch (choiceOint)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (board[0, 0] != "X" && board[0, 0] != "O")
                            {
                                board[0, 0] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[0, 0]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }

                        case 2:
                            if (board[0, 1] != "X" && board[0, 1] != "O")
                            {
                                board[0, 1] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[0, 1]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }

                        case 3:
                            if (board[0, 2] != "X" && board[0, 2] != "O")
                            {
                                board[0, 2] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[0, 2]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 4:
                            if (board[1, 0] != "X" && board[1, 0] != "O")
                            {
                                board[1, 0] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[1, 0]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 5:
                            if (board[1, 1] != "X" && board[1, 1] != "O")
                            {
                                board[1, 1] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[1, 1]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 6:
                            if (board[1, 2] != "X" && board[1, 2] != "O")
                            {
                                board[1, 2] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[1, 2]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 7:
                            if (board[2, 0] != "X" && board[2, 0] != "O")
                            {
                                board[2, 0] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[2, 0]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 8:
                            if (board[2, 1] != "X" && board[2, 1] != "O")
                            {
                                board[2, 1] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[2, 1]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                        case 9:
                            if (board[2, 2] != "X" && board[2, 2] != "O")
                            {
                                board[2, 2] = "O";
                                player++;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"That position on the board is already taken by {board[2, 2]}. Please press enter to try a different position.");
                                Console.Read();
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                }

            }
        }



    }

    public static bool Check4Winner(string[,] board)
    {
        bool win = false;

        int xCounter4Rows;
        int oCounter4Rows;

        int xCounter4Columns;
        int oCounter4Columns;

        int xLRCounter = 0;
        int oLRCounter = 0;

        int xRLCounter = 0;
        int oRLCounter = 0;




        // rows
        for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            xCounter4Rows = 0;
            oCounter4Rows = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (board[i, j] == "X")
                {
                    xCounter4Rows++;
                }
                else if (board[i, j] == "O")
                {
                    oCounter4Rows++;
                }

                if (xCounter4Rows == 3 || oCounter4Rows == 3)
                {
                    win = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // columns
        for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            xCounter4Columns = 0;
            oCounter4Columns = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (board[j, i] == "X")
                {
                    xCounter4Columns++;
                }
                else if (board[j, i] == "O")
                {
                    oCounter4Columns++;
                }
                if (xCounter4Columns == 3 || oCounter4Columns == 3)
                {
                    win = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // left to right diaganol



        for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
        {

            for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (i == j)
                {
                    if (board[i, j] == "X")
                    {
                        xLRCounter++;
                    }
                    else if (board[i, j] == "O")
                    {
                        oLRCounter++;
                    }
                    if (xLRCounter == 3 || oLRCounter == 3)
                    {
                        win = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // right to left diaganol



        for (int a = 0; a < board.GetLength(0); a++)
        {

            for (int b = 2; b > -1; b--)
            {

                if (board[a, b] == "X")
                {
                    xRLCounter++;
                }
                else if (board[a, b] == "O")
                {
                    oRLCounter++;
                }
                if (xRLCounter == 3 || oRLCounter == 3)
                {
                    win = true;
                }

            }
        }


        return win;







    }



}
```

}

Comment: So what error do you get? What is the desired behaviour, what does not work? *Trouble writing* is no error description.

Answer (score 0):

the function Check4Winner is wrong. in the first for loop (//rows) you count the number of X or O in the whole board not in a certain row . in the example you posted there are 3 "X" in the board and the function returned that player 1 is the winner

Comment: I appreciate the response but I'm not sure I see where it's wrong.

within the first for loop I reset the counter variables to zero so in the nested for loop goes through the length of the row and if neither counter is found to equal zero it goes to i++ then so on. 

so it reads [0,0] then [0,1] then [0,2] and if neither counter equals 3 then the loop continues to the next row: [1,0] then [1,1 then [1,2]

Comment: looks like the issue WAS actually in the Check4Winner but it the // right to left diagonal section. Instead of using a nested for loop I just declared the array position variables and the increment rules in the same for loop and bam, it just worked. Then I just added a draw condition to my while loop and it works no problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes your right , i think your just missing these lines